# CSS Transforms Performance

Tags: css, webkit, css-transforms

I wondered what the difference between `-webkit-transform: translate(5px, 5px)` and `-webkit-transform: translateX(5px) translateY(5px)`

Is there any performance difference? Because `translateX` is also used for 3D transforms. So my question is: Is there any difference in calculating the transform? Can I say that `translateX` is faster, because it uses the GPU? Does it?

How can I meassure the performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but `-webkit-transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0)` will be quicker. The two syntaxes you've put are the same, mine uses the 3d context.

Comment: yes you are right. I tested it on a iPad with many elements and then you recognized the differences. But is there any method to meassure the difference in time?

Comment: You could measure the memory usage in Chrome/Safari using the Inspector, but not sure how you'd do it on the device.

Comment: hm ok. BTW there is a small mistake in your answer. It should be `-webkit-transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0)`

Comment: I thought that when I wrote it – I copied your code then edited it, and assumed you must have had it right :)